# Ruckus AccessPoint Javascript need help to post data on Captive Portal

Tags: javascript, php

We are trying to use a captive portal on Ruckus AP for guests.

We have form to post (`username` & `password`). When a user clicks "Login" we need to post this data into the Ruckus AP `user_login_auth.jsp` page and redirect user to another webpage if successful.

However when we click "Login" it goes to `https://IP/user/user_login_auth.jsp` and waits there. How can we see the posted data inside javascript? Is this possible?

Regards. And also I can share the php/javascript code if needed.

Comment: Probably best to post the code

Comment: we **always** need the code.

Answer (score 1):

SOlved ! We change the button name as same as Ruckus button name and it alls match. thanks for no help ! rip stackoverflow.